# Forcing the language culture vs. date/decimal culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, culture

I'm trying to force my application to use the english resource provided, meaning the `en-EN` culture. There's only one problem; I want the dates and decimals to be another culture.

I have forced the language culture by adding the following to the Web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" />
```

Is there an easy way for me to change the dates globally for the entire project, or do I need to format the date on each date input/output around my MVC proejct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change the current thread culture in Global.asax file, and override the date format for example:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
}
```

Comment: For the UI part, you will also need to set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`